# How can I make two functions in Rust run upon spawning a thread?

Tags: multithreading, function, rust

I have the following two functions that I want to call upon spawning the Librarian thread, but only the first function is called. Is there a way I can make both functions call?

```
let Librarian = thread::spawn(move || {
    libReceiveOrder();
    libReceiveBooks();
});
```

Comment: Does the first function never finish? Or does it panic? Those are about the only reasons why the second function wouldn't get called.

Comment: @kmdreko the first function doesn't finish, as both contain messaging queues to receive messages. i was hoping to have the thread alternate between both messaging queues whenever it receives a message, but first i'd have to call the function first. that's when i noticed the issue that the second function never gets called

Comment: You can't have two blocking operations run concurrently on the same thread.

Comment: Sounds like spawning two threads would be the way to go, no?

Comment: *"i was hoping to have the thread alternate between both messaging queues"* - you are 100% describing `async` programming here. Are you sure you really want threading, and not `async` tasks? If you think you might need `async` tasks instead, read this tutorial: https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial

Comment: @kmdreko hi, thanks for the response! i ended up using a separate thread for the other function.

Comment: @Finomnis hi, thanks for the response! will check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to run two functions `libReceiveOrders` and `libReceiveBooks` at once. There are two ways I can recommend you to make that work.

### A - use separate thread per function

This is simple. Just create two more threads, one - for `libReceiveOrders` and another one for `libReceiveBooks`. This will make them run and work with queues.

[Here is full working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a67eea2acb00d92ca6041bd185685664)

### B - use tokio's async methods and especially, tokio::select!

This uses one thread for both functions with [tokio::select! macro](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html). This simplifies synchronization between them, as they can easily share some state without [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). But this also makes your code harder to scale as it utilizes only a single thread for both works. Depend's on your goals what is better here.

[Here is full working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7386dfdf16d5588356a5a9067c911fa9)

Comment: hi, thanks for the detailed response! i ended up using separate threads per function as i'm not familiar with tokio. will check it out, thanks!